# Remove strings from columns with only two strings in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix like this:

```
r1 <- c("01","001","0001","01","100")
r2 <- c("10","001","0001","10","100")
r3 <- c("01","100","1000","10","010")
r4 <- c("01","010","0100","10","001")
r5<- c("01","010","0010","10","001")

n.mat <- rbind(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5)
```

And I would like to remove the second strings in each column with only two strings.

So in the first and fourth column I would like to remove the second strings.

The output should look like this:

```
  r1 <- c("0","001","0001","0","100")
    r2 <- c("1","001","0001","1","100")
    r3 <- c("0","100","1000","1","010")
    r4 <- c("0","010","0100","1","001")
    r5<- c("0","010","0010","1","001")
    
    n.mat <- rbind(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5)
```

I am not sure how to only grep the columns with two strings in it, but I have this:

```
select_if(n.mat, !grepl(""))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sub`:

```
sub("^(.).$", "\\1", n.mat)
#   [,1] [,2]  [,3]   [,4] [,5] 
#r1 "0"  "001" "0001" "0"  "100"
#r2 "1"  "001" "0001" "1"  "100"
#r3 "0"  "100" "1000" "1"  "010"
#r4 "0"  "010" "0100" "1"  "001"
#r5 "0"  "010" "0010" "1"  "001"
```

Or using `nchar` and `substr`:

```
i <- nchar(n.mat)==2
n.mat[i] <- substr(n.mat[i],1,1)
n.mat
#   [,1] [,2]  [,3]   [,4] [,5] 
#r1 "0"  "001" "0001" "0"  "100"
#r2 "1"  "001" "0001" "1"  "100"
#r3 "0"  "100" "1000" "1"  "010"
#r4 "0"  "010" "0100" "1"  "001"
#r5 "0"  "010" "0010" "1"  "001"
```

Or in case for *column with only two strings*:

```
i <- colSums(nchar(n.mat)!=2)==0
n.mat[,i] <- substr(n.mat[,i],1,1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
apply(n.mat, 2, function(x) if(nchar(x) <3) substr(x,1,1) else x)
   [,1] [,2]  [,3]   [,4] [,5] 
r1 "0"  "001" "0001" "0"  "100"
r2 "1"  "001" "0001" "1"  "100"
r3 "0"  "100" "1000" "1"  "010"
r4 "0"  "010" "0100" "1"  "001"
r5 "0"  "010" "0010" "1"  "001"
```

Comment: This could be made more general to take the first character on a cell by cell basis, if columns had a mixture of string lengths: `apply(n.mat, 2, function(x) ifelse(nchar(x) < 3, substr(x,1,1), x))` The `ifelse` function is a vectorized `if`.